# Output is a blank text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Can you explain why my 2 method mergeFile() and mergeData() doesn't work, when i run it give me a blank text file. I really dont understand why ..... Here is my code:

```
String dirName, fileName;

public MergeFile(String dirName, String fileName){
    this.dirName = dirName;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    MergeFile mf = new MergeFile("C:\\Users\\Shine\\Desktop", "C:\\Users\\Shine\\Desktop\\trung.txt");
    mf.mergeData();
}

public void mergeData(){
    for (int i = 0; i < createData().size(); i++){
        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader br;
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try{
            fr = new FileReader(createData().get(i));
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                bw.write(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }catch(IOException exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (bw != null){
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException exp){
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My createData method:

```
public ArrayList<File> createData(){
    File directory = new File(dirName);
    ArrayList<File> file = new ArrayList<>();
    if (directory.isDirectory()){
        for (int i = 0; i < directory.listFiles().length; i++){
            if (directory.listFiles()[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                file.add(directory.listFiles()[i]);
            }
        }
        return file;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

My mergeFile method:

```
public void mergeFile(){
    for (int i = 0; i < createData().size(); i++){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(createData().get(i));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

            int counter;

            while((counter = fis.read()) != -1){
                System.out.println(counter);
                //fos.write(counter);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch(IOException exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wondering this is C#? or Java?

Comment: `System.out` doesn't look like it's C#

Answer (score 0):

Move the declarations

```
FileReader fr;
BufferedReader br;
FileWriter fw;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
```

outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flush()` function inside loop itself after write function